Is it possible to recreate a decision tree model from known fitted parameters (table with nodes)?
I want to recreate the decision tree model based on the published already trained decision tree graph (known parameters are children_left, right, feature, threshold, values, impurity, weighted_n_node_samples, n_node_samples). However, I don't have access to the training data, so I can't fit the classifier.
Are there any possibilities to achieve it using scikit-learn or maybe other tools?
I tried to create the custom classifier, described here Is it possible to use a custom-defined decision tree classifier in Scikit-learn?. However, it also requires fitting, as I understand.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
